# Select values in array that satisfy another condition

Tags: arrays, r

Let's say I have an array of the following form:

```
,,1

    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 34   3     9
[2,] 45   5     8
.
.
,,2
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 21   5    10
[2,] 94   2    10
.
.
```

First I want to select the highest value in the third column of each matrix:

```
apply(array[,3,],2,max)
```

This returns a vector with the highest element in each matrix.

Now I would like to select those values in the second column [,2] of each matrix which have the max value in the third column [,3].

How can I do this?

From the example above the desired output would be:

```
,,1

   3
,,2

   5,2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
lapply(1:dim(arr1)[3], function(i) {
         x1 <- arr1[,,i]
         x1[,2][x1[,3]==max(x1[,3])]})
#[[1]]
#[1] 3

#[[2]]
#[1] 5 2
```